# how to add search functionality in fragment without searchview

Tags: android, android-fragments

**OneFragment**

```
searchitem = v.findViewById(R.id.searchitem);
searchitem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String text = searchitem.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            filter(text);
            Log.d("bfds", "" + text);
        }


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

filter method in onefragment and contactlist is the array list to show data in list

```
private void filter(String text) {
    //new array list that will hold the filtered data

    text = text.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    Log.d("ujhl",""+text);
    //looping through existing elements
    for (HashMap<String, String> s : contactList) {
        //if the existing elements contains the search input
        if (s.containsValue(text.toLowerCase())) {
            //adding the element to filtered list

            contactList.add(s);
            continents = populateContinentData(continents);
            adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), continents);
            Log.d("TY","YTUTY"+continents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new in android so please help me out

Comment: why dont you want to use searchView?

Comment: Please Explain what is problem with code.

Comment: i want go with edittext @NehaK

Comment: post your populateContinentData()

Comment: getting problem in filter @Ashish

Comment: What is `filter(String)` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: passes the value that i called in ontextchangelistener @PPartisan

Comment: post your populateContinentData()

Comment: That's what you pass into the method, but what is the method actually supposed to do? I don't understand its purpose based on the code snippet alone. It would help if you edited your question to include more detail on the problem.

Comment: actually i dont know the flow of filter what should i add i this method @NehaK

Comment: Actually what is the issue occurring ? Filter doesn't work?

Comment: public ArrayList<MainProductName> populateContinentData(ArrayList<MainProductName> continents) {
        // Asia MainProductName

        for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
            MainProductName conti = new MainProductName(0 + i, "" + contactList.get(i).get("ITEM_NAME"), null, R.drawable.moong);// new MainProductName(i,myname[i].toString(), null, R.drawable.asia);
            ArrayList<SubProductName> country = new ArrayList<>(); @NehaK

Comment: can you post MainProductName.java ?

Comment: array list  to show ,main product @NehaK

Comment: in MainProductName i did getter setter name id rate @NehaK

Comment: hi welcome to stack overflow. you want to fitler your result on key base or value base in HashMap?

Comment: You can do filter with two types. Override filter method in adapter or just make your own method for filter

Comment: please explain @Piyush

Comment: Are you using custom class list for populate your adapter?

Comment: yes i used expandablelist  @Piyush

Comment: This _MainProductName_ list passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it in a wrong way You can't iterate **HashMap** using **foreach** loop and one more you are calling getText() on your **EditText** (i am supposing) every time when there's a change in text.

```
String text = searchitem.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
```

so there's no need of doing this. You can use **CharSequence s** to filter your list as

```
searchitem.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            filter(s); // get this **s** as queryText in filter method
            Log.d("bfds", "" + text);
        }


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

as i said earlier you can't use foreach for hashmap so you can only fitler your hashmap on two basis

1. Key Base `List<Stirng> keys= contactList.keySet();`
2. Value Base `List<Stirng> values= contactList.values();`

   ```
   for (String s : keys/values) {
   // if list item contains the input string char sequence
   if (s.toLowerCase().containsValue(queryText.toLowerCase())) {
       //add to your fitler list and set to adapter here
   }

   //or you can use startsWith to check if list item string starts with input char sequence like
    if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith(queryText.toLowerCase())) {
       //add to fitlered list and set to adapter here
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
private void filter(String text) {
    //new array list that will hold the filtered data
    HashMap<String, String> contactListFiltered = new HashMap<String, String>();
    text = text.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    Log.d("ujhl",""+text);
    //looping through existing elements
    for (HashMap<String, String> s : contactList) {
        //if the existing elements contains the search input
        if (s.containsValue(text.toLowerCase())) {
            //adding the element to filtered list
            contactListFiltered.putAll(s);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<MainProductName> continents = populateContinentData(contactListFiltered);
    adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), continents);
    yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("TY","YTUTY"+continents);
}

public ArrayList<MainProductName> populateContinentData(HashMap<String, String> contactList) {
    // Asia MainProductName

    ArrayList<MainProductName> products = new ArrayList();
     for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
         MainProductName conti = new MainProductName(i, "" + contactList.get(i), null, R.drawable.moong);
         products.add(conti);
     }

     return products;
}
```

and let us know the result

Comment: this is not the solution. did you test it? if yes then you probably see an error in foreach sytax that you cant iterate your hashMap by foreach loop.

Comment: How can i test it i dont have all code, thats why I asked her "let us know the result"

Comment: and hashmap is contained in list, not iterating through a HaspMap, its iterating a Array which contains hashMaps

Comment: contactList is array of Hashmaps

Comment: i tried but when i am typing on search my list is not showing blank ppage @NehaK

Comment: try to debug code line by line and find the solution, this will help you learning also